# Opencart option_value_id

Tags: php, opencart, vqmod

OpenCart attaches an html `value=""` attribute to each `<option>` for `<select>` elements on Product pages.  Currently it uses `product_option_value_id`. I need to change that to use the `option_value_id` from the `oc_product_option_value` table.

I have created a vQmod to replace this line in my theme's `product.tpl` file.

```
<option value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
```

I tried using `$option_value['option_value_id'];` but that returns the `product_option_id`? I can't figure out what variable to use to achieve this for select options.

Do I need to write a new query to grab this data, or is this data in a variable that is visible already in `product.tpl`?

Comment: It's hard to comprehend what you are trying to do here. You need to explain more. In regards to the question of is the data in any array: the simplest way to check would be to do a `print_r` on any of the variables such as `$option_value`

Comment: For what it's worth, the reason I am doing this is so that my jQuery will work for all products with a particular option. Currently, I have to hard code each specific product's value for that option. If i can use the select option's id, then it will work for all products that use that option. #respect

Answer (score 1):

These are the contents of `$this->data['options']` array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array

        [product_option_id] => 300
        [option_id] => 5
        [name] => Select
        [type] => select
        [option_value] => Array

                [0] => Array

                        [product_option_value_id] => 110
                        [option_value_id] => 39
                        [name] => Red
                        [image] => 
                        [price] => 
                        [price_prefix] => +

                [1] => Array

                        [product_option_value_id] => 109
                        [option_value_id] => 40
                        [name] => Blue
                        [image] => 
                        [price] => 
                        [price_prefix] => +

        [required] => 1
```

`[option_id]` and `[option_value_id]` are constant for all products that have this option assigned. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for helping me, appreciated. Yeah, I need to use the option_value_id as it is constant. It seemed so simple when I started this 2 days ago. I still can't seem to get at that data though in my product.tpl? What variable in product.tpl refers to this field? Every time I think I'm getting it, it spits out the product_option_id and I can't see that being set anywhere in the model and controller files?

Comment: Whenever you see `$this->data['foo']` in the controller, it's `$foo`   in the tpl.

Comment: Right, thank you. I had tried `$options['0']['option_value']['0']['option_value_id']` which should give me 39 from your example above, correct? On my site `$options['0']['option_value']['0']['option_value_id']` would return 110?

Comment: I have Q's options boost installed, I am going to check those files to see if any mods have been made that might be causing my problem. I can't figure this out. I feel stupid right now.

Comment: Ah, yes. I know that mod. It overwrites default options. You need to check it's output, correct.

Comment: There is this line `foreach ($post_option as $option_id => $option_value_id)` in _options_boost_vqmod.xml_ The mod is adding code before, not replacing the existing. Is that line responsible?

Comment: I don't have this mod right now, so can't be sure. Just do a `print_r` in your controller to see the resulting array.

Comment: Thank you, i'm still learning php. print_r (with echo <pre>) on `$option_value` in my controller displays the correct `option_value_id` for each option. This is expected, great it should work. No, using `$option_value['option_value_id']` echo's the value of `$option_value['product_option_value_id']`